# Open excel file in Tkinter and plot graphs

Tags: excel, python-3.x, plot, tkinter, widget

I've just started writing Python a month ago and now getting into Tkinter. I'm trying to build a program that a user can open an excel file into Tkinter, display the dataframe and the user can choose a certain graph type, insert the variables for the X-axis and Y-axis and plot it. I've build the general layout of the GUI using PAGE but having problems on how to give commands to the widgets on displaying the dataframe and plotting the graph.

Here's my code for the GUI:

```
import sys
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    top = New_Toplevel_1 (root)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_New_Toplevel_1(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = Toplevel (root)
    top = New_Toplevel_1 (w)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_New_Toplevel_1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class New_Toplevel_1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        self._bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        self._fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        self._compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        self._ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        self._ana2color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 

        top.geometry("757x1037+832+67")
        top.title("New Toplevel 1")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        top.configure(highlightcolor="black")


        self.Canvas1 = Canvas(top)
        self.Canvas1.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.58, relheight=0.4, relwidth=0.92)
        self.Canvas1.configure(background="white")
        self.Canvas1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.Canvas1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Canvas1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Canvas1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Canvas1.configure(relief=RIDGE)
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Canvas1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Canvas1.configure(width=695)

        self.Button2 = Button(top)
        self.Button2.place(relx=0.75, rely=0.52, height=42, width=138)
        self.Button2.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button2.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button2.configure(text='''Generate Graph''')

        self.Labelframe1 = LabelFrame(top)
        self.Labelframe1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.39, relheight=0.18
                , relwidth=0.44)
        self.Labelframe1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
        self.Labelframe1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(text='''Type of Graph''')
        self.Labelframe1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Labelframe1.configure(width=330)

        self.Radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Radiobutton1.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.22, relheight=0.2
                , relwidth=0.31)
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(justify=LEFT)
        self.Radiobutton1.configure(text='''Bar Chart''')

        self.Radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Radiobutton2.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.38, relheight=0.2
                , relwidth=0.35)
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(justify=LEFT)
        self.Radiobutton2.configure(text='''Histogram''')

        self.Radiobutton3 = Radiobutton(self.Labelframe1)
        self.Radiobutton3.place(relx=0.06, rely=0.54, relheight=0.2
                , relwidth=0.37)
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(justify=LEFT)
        self.Radiobutton3.configure(text='''Scatter Plot''')

        self.Button3 = Button(top)
        self.Button3.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.05, height=52, width=122)
        self.Button3.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button3.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button3.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button3.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button3.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button3.configure(text='''Browse''')
        self.Button3.configure(width=122)
        self.Button3.configure(command=askopenfilename)

        self.Label5 = Label(top)
        self.Label5.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.06, height=31, width=147)
        self.Label5.configure(activebackground="#f9f9f9")
        self.Label5.configure(activeforeground="black")
        self.Label5.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label5.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label5.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label5.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label5.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Label5.configure(text='''Upload File:''')
        self.Label5.configure(width=147)

        self.Label3 = Label(top)
        self.Label3.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.13, height=31, width=111)
        self.Label3.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label3.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label3.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label3.configure(text='''Data Frame :''')

        self.Text1 = Text(top)
        self.Text1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.16, relheight=0.21, relwidth=0.9)
        self.Text1.configure(background="white")
        self.Text1.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.Text1.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Text1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Text1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.Text1.configure(selectforeground="black")
        self.Text1.configure(width=684)
        self.Text1.configure(wrap=WORD)

        self.Labelframe2 = LabelFrame(top)
        self.Labelframe2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.39, relheight=0.12
                , relwidth=0.45)
        self.Labelframe2.configure(relief=GROOVE)
        self.Labelframe2.configure(foreground="black")
        self.Labelframe2.configure(text='''Labelframe''')
        self.Labelframe2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Labelframe2.configure(width=340)

        self.Label1 = Label(self.Labelframe2)
        self.Label1.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.24, height=31, width=67)
        self.Label1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label1.configure(text='''X-axis :''')

        self.Label2 = Label(self.Labelframe2)
        self.Label2.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.56, height=31, width=66)
        self.Label2.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Label2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Label2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Label2.configure(text='''Y-axis :''')

        self.Entry1 = Entry(self.Labelframe2)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.24, relheight=0.29, relwidth=0.72)
        self.Entry1.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry1.configure(width=244)

        self.Entry2 = Entry(self.Labelframe2)
        self.Entry2.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.56, relheight=0.29, relwidth=0.72)
        self.Entry2.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry2.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry2.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry2.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry2.configure(insertbackground="black")
        self.Entry2.configure(width=244)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    vp_start_gui()
```

I know how to save the data into a dataframe and plot graphs in Python, but i'm not sure where to write those codes when GUI is involved. All i was able to do was give a command to the 'Browse' button to search for the excel file.

```
self.Button3.configure(command=askopenfilename)
```

Can someone help me:

1. How to save the excel file chosen from the command into a dataframe
2. How to display the dataframe into the textbox below
3. How to plot the graph with the criteria (type of graph and axes) chosen onto the canvas at bottom

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: `command=my_own_function_to_open_file_and_do_other_things`

Comment: @furas i've thought about that, but then how would i pass variables or dataframes from that function into other functions?

Comment: call other functions directly in this function. Or use `self.variable` to keep information.

Comment: @furas i'm not really familiar with the`self.variable` concept, could you elaborate more? For instance, i've created my own function to read the excel file and save into a dataframe(df). How can i pass the df into another function to print out the data in the textbox, or pass the df to plot the graph?

Comment: you already use `self.variable` - ie `self.Canvas1`, `self.Button2`, etc. and this variables are accessible in all class methods. If you assign value to `self.df` in one class method then you can use it in another class method.

Answer (score 1):

In class use some `self.variable` to keep information and then you can use it in other methods in class.

In example I use method `load()` to load file and create dataframe, and method `display()` to display this dataframe in text widget.

```
try:
    # Python 2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

import pandas as pd

# --- classes ---

class MyWindow:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent = parent

        self.filename = None
        self.df = None

        self.text = tk.Text(self.parent)
        self.text.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='LOAD DATA', command=self.load)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self.parent, text='DISPLAY DATA', command=self.display)
        self.button.pack()

    def load(self):

        name = askopenfilename(filetypes=[('CSV', '*.csv',), ('Excel', ('*.xls', '*.xlsx'))])

        if name:
            if name.endswith('.csv'):
                self.df = pd.read_csv(name)
            else:
                self.df = pd.read_excel(name)

            self.filename = name

            # display directly
            #self.text.insert('end', str(self.df.head()) + '\n')

    def display(self):
        # ask for file if not loaded yet
        if self.df is None:
            self.load()

        # display if loaded
        if self.df is not None:
            self.text.insert('end', self.filename + '\n')
            self.text.insert('end', str(self.df.head()) + '\n')


# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = MyWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes thank you! All i needed was a clear example to understand, thanks (: One last question, you don't by any chance know how to plot a graph onto a canvas would you?

Comment: pandas uses matplotlib which can work with different GUIs - tkinter, wxPython, PyQt - you have to set in matplot what GUI you use and it can give you access to widget (with plot) which you can embed in GUI. https://pythonprogramming.net/how-to-embed-matplotlib-graph-tkinter-gui/

Answer (score 1):

Here i have fetch the excel data and store it in the graph, but i want my graph should plot data after 5 second,and the graph should run in the Run time.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# read  from excel file
wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Acer-i5-607\\Desktop\\case1.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('case1')

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4), facecolor='Grey')
G = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 2)
axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[0, :])


x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=4).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('HR')
plt.plot(x, y, color='cyan', label='HR')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)
#plt.title('Reading values from an Excel file'

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[1, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=6).value

#print a
#print b

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Pulse')
plt.plot(x, y, color='red', label='Pulse')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[2, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=7).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('SpO2')
plt.plot(x, y, color='magenta', label='SpO2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[3, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=8).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Perf')
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue', label='Perf')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)


axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[4, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=9).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('etCO2')
plt.plot(x, y, color='yellow', label='etCO2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)


axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[5, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=10).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('imCO2')
plt.plot(x, y, color='green', label='imCO2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)

plt.xlim(0, 60000)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue')
canvas1.pack()

def getExcel ():
    global df
    
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)
    df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year"], format="%Y")
    ax = df.plot("Year", "Accidents",marker='o',color='r')
    plt.grid()
    plt.title('Yearly Graph')
    ax.figure.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.show()
    
    
browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Import Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_Excel)

root.mainloop()
```